# Does anyone know this handwriting font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I just was wondering what font is used for the window descriptions, such as crisps & snacks, refresh and revive, its a very nice handwriting style font. Thanks for your help.

[image: a shop window]

Answer (score 1):

Look pretty similar to [Festus! font](http://www.dafont.com/festus.font):

[image]

Comment: It looks the same apart from the 'P'. Maybe they edited it?

Comment: @SaturnsEye the word "Plus" not a part of a question, anyway the letter "P" looks custom letter

Comment: Is the "Plus" not the same typeface as the rest? the "S" looks the same.

Comment: @SaturnsEye the word "Plus" is part of a "logo"/signboard, it is usual to make it custom in some way... and the one way to do that - to change the style of an already used font so save the similarity...

Comment: Hmm yes, I guess so :)

Comment: The P is actually formed with a + sign (That's why the bowl has a gap in it).

Comment: Thanks for the font reply, much appreciated. In regard to the P I think its the same font, but they've perhaps converted the text to outlines and used the pathfinder tool to subtract a bit for variation.